# Do not display THIS if iPad/iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, if-statement, browser-detection

I have a flash advert I do not want to display on iPhones and iPads.

What's wrong with this conditional?

```
<?php 
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod')) { 
// do something 
} 
else { 
// do something else 
} 
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(strstr($SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
```

Specifies "iPod" for the second match. Change that to 'iPad'. If you want to do the same for the iPod touch, you'll also need a clause for iPod as you have currently.

The following should work for all 3:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad'))
```

Comment: Why did you remove all the underscores?

Comment: They weren't in the original question. I've put them back in.

Comment: Hah, call it a "wood for trees" moment. Was just highlighting the other typo.

Comment: I don't have an iPad handy but for iPhone doesn't work? I am assuming it's the same case for iPad as I still get the Not iPad/Iphone echo from { echo "iPad/iPhone"; } else { echo "Not iPad/iPhone"; } ?>.

Comment: And yes, I initially wrote $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] without underlines :).

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your current code for iPhone, have you tried outputting the user agent string above the if statement as a double check?

Comment: Just did with $var = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; echo $var; and it's different on desktop computer and my iPhone but still, the string from the conditional (NOT) is still displayed on both.

Comment: But was output when you echoed $var?

Comment: So this one is alright for my dekstop and iPhone but not for the iPad, just checked = if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone')); how do i target the iPad then? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6548/discussion-between-tom-elliott-and-cristian-demetriad)

Comment: Yes, I have the user agent output which looks alright and then the echoed strings which are "NOT" for desktop/iPad, but "OK" for iPhone so I guess it's a matter of targeting the iPad now.